# Cannot feed value of shape for Tensor Placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a model using 3D point cloud data in TensorFlow. My batch size is 64, so TensorFlow expects to receive batch of 64 of 3D points like: (64,1024,3). When I run the training code:

```
feed_dict = {ops['points_pl']: augmented_data,
                     ops['labels_pl']: current_label[start_idx:end_idx],
                     ops['w_pl']: gmm.weights_,
                     ops['mu_pl']: gmm.means_,
                     ops['sigma_pl']: np.sqrt(gmm.covariances_),
                     ops['is_training_pl']: is_training, }
        summary, step, _, loss_val, pred_val = sess.run([ops['merged'], ops['step'],
                                                         ops['train_op'], ops['loss'], ops['pred']],
                                                        feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

In the last batch because the remaining data is less than 64, I get this error:

```
 ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (36, 1024, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0', which has shape '(64, 1024, 3)'
```

I tried to manually add data at end of a batch when it is smaller than 64 but it significantly reduced the performance. When I set batch size to 1,2,4 it works okay but it ran very slowly. How can I get rid of this problem in an efficient way? Is there a way that TF to recognize such a situation and continue training without throwing an error?

Comment: We don't have any context for what your data looks like, or how your model is defined. Can you please provide us with some context to frame your question?

Comment: my data is point cloud. I do object recognition. Each object is defined by 1024 three dimensional points. So, an object is (1,1024,3). when batch size is 64 I have (64,1024,3) in each iteration. Sometimes (usually in the last iteration) less number of instances remains like abovementioned example 34 instances and causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the size of the batch dimension precisely. Instead you put None as the size of that dimension. You can define your placeholders e.g.:

```
n1 = 1024
n2 = 3
ops['points_pl'] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n1, n2]) 
ops['labels_pl'] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
```

Tensorflow will then allow you to feed those placeholders arrays without any restriction on the first dimension. This solves the problem of the final batch, and is also useful during inference (when you may want to apply the model to a different number of inputs than your batch size).

Comment: well, my model is defined as:     with tf.device('/gpu:'+str(GPU_INDEX)):
            points_pl, labels_pl, w_pl, mu_pl, sigma_pl = MODEL.placeholder_inputs(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_POINT, gmm )
            is_training_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=())

Comment: when I replace BATCH_SIZE with None it gives another error

Comment: MODEL.placeholder_inputs is not some standard Tensorflow function so I cannot comment on what happens inside. Sometimes a network is constructed with the batch_size built in somehow e.g. in a reshape command. In this case, presuming you have enough data, I would just skip the final batch if it is not of size 64.

Comment: Yeah I can skip the last batch, however, I wanted to process all the data. You see that the reshape command comes after but I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Presumably your training will have more than one epoch, and the data is reshuffled before every epoch, so the items in the last batch will still occur in other epochs. Other than that I don't have any suggestions unfortunately.